# Project name change keeps asking to checkout

Tags: tfs, ssis, project

I have a solution with a few SSIS projects, which is in TFS. I was helping a guy fix some project names to be consistent with the other projects in the solution. After updating the names, we checked in the project and the solution files. When I got latest (I tried both GetLatest and GetSpecific), TFS kept asking me to checkout those project files and it got pretty annoying and I ended up checking them out and then undid my changes on the project files.

Does anyone know why it keeps doing that?

Comment: You renamed the project files and checked them in. Did TFS recognize the change to the files as a rename or did it see "oh we have *new* files"? Based on your question, I'm assuming the later. Either way, I think we'd need to see the what your TFS looked like before/after the change.

Comment: I'll add some more information once I go to work tomorrow

Comment: While checking in make sure that you go the View // All pending changes. Sometimes there are more files to be checked in that are visible from within the Solution explorer windows. Also, get the latest before making changes.

Comment: @AnoopVerma: Its not that. I always check in all files